# Writing contents of a DirectSound CaptureBuffer to a WAV file in C#

Tags: c#, audio, wav, directsound

I have recorded audio to a CaptureBuffer, but I can't figure out how to save it into wav file. I have tried this (http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=4782), but it didn't work, or I didn't use it properly. Does anybody know how to solve this? Sample code would be very appreciated.

Comment: That code is very dependent on the 8-bit mono format of the sample data. What sort of sample rate / bit format are you using to record your data with?

Comment: I don't know, I am using StartRecord() function from that link. Actually I have never worked with sound before, so I am a little disoriented here.

Comment: I just copied the code from that link into a new library. And then added reference to this library from my program. Then I declared an object of class "SoundRec" and tried to use it. But somehow the program just freezes whenever I run it.

Comment: Well, you can always convert to bytes and save with BinaryWriter.

Comment: To Quantic Programming: How do I do that? Can you give some example code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A WAV file is a RIFF file consisting of two main "chunks". The first is a format chunk, describing the format of the audio. This will be what sample rate you recorded at (e.g. 44.1kHz), what bit depth (e.g. 16 bits) and how many channels (mono or stereo). WAV also supports compressed formats but it is unlikely you recorded the audio compressed, so your record buffer will contain PCM audio.

Then there is the data chunk. This is the part of the WAV file that contains the actual audio data in your capture buffer. This must be in the format described in the format chunk.

As part of the [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) project I created a [WaveFileWriter](http://naudio.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/76093#7823) class to simplify creating WAV files. You pass in a WaveFormat that describes the format of your captured audio. Then you can simply write the raw captured data in.

Here's some simple example code for how you might use WaveFileWriter:

```
WaveFormat format = new WaveFormat(16000, 16, 1); // for mono 16 bit audio captured at 16kHz
using (var writer = new WaveFileWriter("out.wav", format)
{
    writer.WriteData(captureBuffer, 0, captureBuffer.Length);
}
```