# Receiving audio data from multiple sources and merging them into a wave file

Tags: c#, wav, audio-recording, naudio, directsound

I'm using C# and DirectSound to record audio and send it across a local network to another computer that receives the data and saves it into a wave file.

I used similar [code for recording](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tamir/archive/2008/12/25/capturing-and-streaming-sound-by-using-directsound-with-c.aspx) and similar [for saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729594/writing-contents-of-a-directsound-capturebuffer-to-a-wav-file-in-c-sharp) the wave file (using NAudio).

Saving all received bytes into a wave file works. But, I would like to receive audio from multiple computers and merge it into a single wave file.

I tried to record two separate wave files, one for each client, then merging them together. However, my naive approach does not provide any means of synchronization. The resulting wave files differ in length by at least 5 seconds and cannot be appropriately merged.

So, here are my questions:

1) How can I take audio bytes received from a network and save them into a wave file in such way that the resulting file plays back audio at the correct time?

For instance, I record 100 seconds of audio and send it across the network. But, only 95 seconds of audio bytes are actually recorded. The missing 5 seconds results from the accumulation of the small delays that occur while I send packets.

So, how can I synchronize those 95 seconds of audio to playback at the right time, during 100 seconds?

2) How can I mix the audio bytes I receive from multiple clients to obtain a single wave file that plays the audio of all clients in sync?

Please let me know if I need to clarify my question. I appreciate any assistance!

Comment: do you need time x to be the same on all senders? i.e. should they have the same timebase?

Comment: If you make a loud noise, I want it to show up on all recordings at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need high-precision time synchronization on the participating computers (plus timestamps on the sent packets).  To minimize clock drift, you can re-sync at pre-determined intervals (less preferred) or install higher quality hardware clocks in the machines (preferred).  If these machines are on a local network, setting up one as an NTP server and the others as clients will yield sufficiently sync'd clocks (i.e., within .000001 seconds of one another or better).

Comment: @aleph_null So, you're going to throw away 25 reputation rather than accept the answer and let the fully bounty be rewarded?

Comment: No, I will have a very busy day and remember to select an answer right before the deadline... and then have a hard time selecting the answer since they're both the same!

Comment: @aleph_null I disagree that the answers are the same though.  Timestamps were not mentioned until after much discussion on the other answer (and that was a couple of days after I posted this).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to synchronize audio from multiple sources then you need to buffer the data at the receiving end. Don't write or play any audio data until you have at least BUFFERSIZE samples from every participating source. You will have to adjust BUFFERSIZE based on your network latency.

You can do this using two threads, one to write or play the audio data and the other to buffer the incoming streams. When BUFFERSIZE samples have been received from each audio source, the receiving thread passes all the data to the other thread to write or play. It will usually always be the case that most streams have more than BUFFERSIZE samples. You would have to keep these leftovers around for the next fill-up.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it'll only work if all programs are sending audio at exactly the same rate. For instance, one audio transmitting device i'm using is an android and tends to have a tiny delay between recording audio packets. Thus, recording 100 seconds results in 95 seconds of audio. So, the audio would be unsynchronized. Let me know if I need to clarify.

Comment: No, buffering the data specifically addresses the issue of audio being sent at different rates. As long as the buffer is large enough to compensate for the difference in transmission rate between the fastest and slowest source, you're ok.

Comment: @VinnieFalco is right. The network connections need to keep the buffer queues topped up while the audio player empties them at a constant rate.  The cost you pay is in extra latency, but there is little choice.

Comment: But, say that I have a computer and an android device in the same room and clap really loud after 100 seconds of recording. The computer records 99 seconds of audio while the android device records 95 seconds. (I made up the numbers but they illustrate what happens). The clap shows up four seconds apart on each recording.

Comment: If you want the audio streams to be mixed together synchronized in time, then mark the beginning of each stream with the absolute time from a reliable source. You will still need to buffer, but in addition to the difference between the fastest and slowest source you will also need to factor in the starting time difference between the sources. When you mix the stream together you'll have to be aware of time-synchronization.